# Kibana: meaning of iframe url parameters

Tags: iframe, kibana

I want to build my own web server with tomcat where I can import kibana graphs and dashboard. I found that I can use the iframe urls to do so. Furthermore, in the url there are parameters that I can change in order to modify my graphs and dashboard in function of my data. However, I haven't found any documentation in the elastic website explaining the meaning of each parameters. Can you indicate me a source ?

Furthermore, I also have a question regarding the dashbord exported. The graphs inside the dashboard can be still dragged and I would like to know if there is a parameter to disable this functionnality.

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Joe

Comment: I found this: https://rawgit.com/sk4zuzu/kibana-rison-json-converter/master/index.html

Comment: the url is in rison